# Why is powershell constantly giving me an AttributeError for this class based program in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am currently learning classes on Zed Shaw's book: Learn Python The Hard Way, and I am copying code from his book, but it appears that - despite carrying out all checks for any spelling or indentation mistakes - Powershell gives me an AtrributeError when running the program.
First, here is the code:

```
class Song(object):

    def __init__(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

        def sing_me_a_song(self):
            for line in self.lyrics:
                print(line)

happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you",
                    "I don't want to get sued",
                    "So I'll stop right there"])

bulls_on_parade = Song(["They rally around tha family",
                        "With pockets full of shells"])

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()

bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()
```

Powershell gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex40.py", line 17, in <module>
    happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()
AttributeError: 'Song' object has no attribute 'sing_me_a_song'
```

What is wrong with my program and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Incorrect indentation so that `sing_me_a_song` is local to `__init__`.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Thanks!